# How to compile and run Stanford's Karel with the command line?

Tags: java, command-line

This program compiles and runs swimmingly in eclipse on the same machine, but I'd really like to work from the command line and my editor of choice.

**CollectNewspaperKarel.java**

```
import stanford.karel.*;

    public class CollectNewspaperKarel extends SuperKarel {

        public void run() {
            // You fill in this part
        }

    }
```

The karel.jar is in the same directory as the file above.

**Compile**

```
javac -cp karel.jar CollectNewspaperKarel.java
```

with no errors.

**Run**

```
java -cp karel.jar CollectNewspaperKarel

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CollectNewspaperKarel
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CollectNewspaperKarel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: In all honesty, I hated using eclipse when I was in school, and I regret resisting it. Not that this is a bad question, nor something important to know, but just a personal experience. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to include your class to classpath when running the program.

Try this - if running on windows:

```
java -cp karel.jar;CollectNewspaperKarel.class CollectNewspaperKarel
```

or this if you're running on linux:

```
java -cp karel.jar:CollectNewspaperKarel.class CollectNewspaperKarel
```

One more thing however, you need to have main method in your class, otherwise it won't work :)

**Update:**

I've found following site: http://ycsoftware.net/setting-up-karel-the-robot-in-eclipse/

seems, you should go with the following arguments if you have the same version of karel as the author there:

on windows:

```
java -cp karel.jar;CollectNewspaperKarel.class stanford.karel.Karel code=CollectNewspaperKarel
```

on linux:

```
java -cp karel.jar:CollectNewspaperKarel.class stanford.karel.Karel code=CollectNewspaperKarel
```

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction.  Your updated command for linux needs to be `s/;/:` and now I get another exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at acm.program.Program.main(Program.java:917)
 at stanford.karel.Karel.main(Karel.java:202)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565032/npe-at-acm-program-program-mainprogram-java917 and with `java -cp .:karel.jar:acm.jar:CollectNewspaperKarel.class stanford.karel.Karel code=CollectNewspaperKarel` i'm golden.  thanks guys!

Comment: @Robert adding .: before karel.jar fixed it for me as well

Answer (score 1):

Peter B. is right, however you cannot run a class containing a "run" method alone, you need a public static void(String[] args) method to make it runnable.

I suppose that in Eclipse some other class is used as a "main class" to run the thing.